# CakePHP 3 AuthComponent::login() equivalent -> id missing?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, acl

I'm trying to set up [cakephp/acl](https://github.com/cakephp/acl) and using [this example](https://github.com/mattmemmesheimer/cakephp-3-acl-example) as a guide.  The only main difference is that I'm using email instead of username and have accounted for this with:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'email']               
            ]
        ],
        ...
```

The login itself seems to work but when I navigate to a controller eg: /posts/index I get the following error

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aros node identified by "Array ( [Aros0.model] => Users [Aros0.foreign_key] => 1 ) "
```

My knowledge of Acl is rudimentary, so I'm having trouble figuring this out.

A couple of similar issues I've seen are based on CakePHP 2, and talk about having the id set in the AuthComponent::login.  [Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/croogo/0ak7qvERONk) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24269315/aclnodenode-couldnt-find-aro-node-identified-by-array-aro0-model) but I have no idea how this translates into CakePHP 3, or why I am having this issue in the first place.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: where is your password field?